# CSS Animation - Swell Effect

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to create a CSS animation on a standard ASCII character (specifically this: •). I want my animation to be a swell effect like [this](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/source/attention_seekers/pulse.css). For some reason though, the character just moves from left to right. It doesn't swell up and return to normal size as you can see in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/nfpx4qzeFd).

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">  
<div id="dot" class="dot">•</div>
  <button id="expandButton">push me</button>
</div>

.dot {
  font-size:3.0rem;
}

.dot-expand {
  color:green;
  animation: dot-expander 3.0s;
}

@keyframes dot-expander {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything looks correct to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the CSS animation by just using scale and not scale3D (especially since all 3 values were the same scale - there's no benefit to using scale3D here)... also the difference between a scale of 1 and a scale of 1.05 is almost unintelligible to the viewer, especially if it takes 3 seconds to cycle (at least in this instance, at the size of the element).

Here's a working example (I edited time and scaling a bit so it is more clearly shown.)

```js
$('#expandButton').on('click', function() {
  //toggleClass to turn off the animation on second button click.
   $('#dot').toggleClass('dot-expand');
 });
```

```css
* {margin: 20px; }

.dot {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px; 
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
  display: block;
}

.dot-expand {
  animation: dot-expander 2s infinite; /* remove 'infinate' if you just want 1 cycle */
}

@keyframes dot-expander {
  0% {
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }

  50% {
  background: rgb(0,255,0);
    transform: scale(2.5);
  }

  100% {
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">  
<div id="dot" class="dot"></div>
  <button id="expandButton">push me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because you're trying to scale a text element with scale. Instead, use css to create a circle div.

**CSS:**

```
.dot {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px; 
    background: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.dot-expand {
  background: rgb(0,255,0);
  animation: dot-expander 3.0s;
}

@keyframes dot-expander {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }

  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">  
<div id="dot" class="dot">•</div>
  <button id="expandButton">push me</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#expandButton').on('click', function() {
  alert('here');
  $('#dot').addClass('dot-expand');
});
```

**Demo: http://www.bootply.com/9FwMTQQHoO**

I'd recommend you increase the scale amount, as the effect is very subtle. You may also want to remove the .dot-expand class after the animation has finished, because currently the animation can only be played once. For the animation to be played again without a page reload, the class needs to be removed and added again when the button is pressed.